# switch views from one page to another when the button is clicked in angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, redirect

I am new to angular JS.How can I redirect to another page when the button is clicked.
My code here

```
var app = angular.module("plunker", [])
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

$routeProvider.when('/home',
{
  templateUrl:    'home.html',
  controller:     'HomeCtrl'
});
$routeProvider.when('/about',
{
  templateUrl:    'about.html',
  controller:     'AboutCtrl'
});
$routeProvider.when('/contact',
{
  templateUrl:    'contact.html',
  controller:     'ContactCtrl'
});
$routeProvider.otherwise(
{
  redirectTo:     '/home',
  controller:     'HomeCtrl', 
}
```

);
});

```
app.controller('NavCtrl', 
['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {  
$scope.navClass = function (page) {
var currentRoute = $location.path().substring(1) || 'home';
return page === currentRoute ? 'active' : '';
};
   }]);

app.controller('AboutCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
console.log('inside about controller');


});

app.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
console.log('inside home controller');
```

//redirect when button click
    function Cntrl ($scope,$location) {
        $scope.redirect = function(){
        window.location.href = '/about';
}
    }

});

app.controller('ContactCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
  console.log('inside contact controller');

});

my html markup is

```
<div ng-controller="Cntrl">
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="changeView('about')">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

You entered :

How to get this.help me to solve this .

Answer (score 2):

Just use a standard HTML link :

```
<div ng-controller="Cntrl">
    <a class="btn btn-success" ng-href="#/about">Click Me</a>        
</div>
```

No need to create a scope function for that. You can also handle that dynamically thanks to [ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) :

```
<div ng-controller="Cntrl">
    <a class="btn btn-success" ng-href="#/{{view}}">Click Me</a>        
</div>
```

Last thing, you should consider using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) which handle even better this cases

Comment: It is , it's just the way angular works, you have another problem somewhere, take a look at the ng-href doc link I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to send the view as a param:

Try this:

```
$scope.changeView = function() {
            $location.path(#/about); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If solution that Cétia presented does not work, then it is possible that you do not have your routes defined. Make sure that you have your route defined withing app.js like this :

```
  app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/Login', {
                templateUrl: 'Navigate/LoginView',
                controller: 'someLoginController'
            })

]);
```

You can as well use angulars state provider (do some research) and from state provider you can access your routes within html as :

```
<a href="state.routName" />
```